# Safe to do case insensitive lookup on AES encrypted string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, encryption, cryptography

After following this MSDN article on the `AesCryptoServiceProvider` `AesCryptoServiceProvider.CreateEncryptor` example (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356459(v=vs.110).aspx), see snippet below.

```
static string EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    // Check arguments.
    if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
    if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
    byte[] encrypted;
    // Create an AesCryptoServiceProvider object
    // with the specified key and IV.
    using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        aesAlg.Key = Key;
        aesAlg.IV = IV;

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for encryption.
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {

                    //Write all data to the stream.
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                }
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }



    return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);

}
```

I am able to use this method and generated encrypted strings successfully, however when I started saving the encrypted strings in a SQL database I realised that any lookup would be case-insensitive. My question is, is it okay to do a case insensitive lookup on an encrypted value using this method? What are the chances that the method will produce the same string but in a different case?

The other alternative is to retrieve the values from the database and do case sensitive lookup in memory, but im trying to avoid that.

Technologies use. 
C#, EntityFramework, Azure SQL Server 2016, ASP.NET MVC, WEB API

Comment: Currently the value is byte[], for which the question makes no sense.  If it's turned into a string then you have (effectively) two choices: Base64 and hex.  For hex case is irrelevant.  For Base64 it's significant and therefore cannot be matched insensitively.

Comment: Ah of course, i forgot add my other code that does a `return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);`. Converting to hex makes sense. I was interested to know how others dealt with the SQL case sensitivity problem.

Comment: By saving it as hex, or base32, instead of base64 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @bartonjs, saving the output as Base32 or HEX will solve the case sensitivity problem. See the gist here for an example of Base32 Encoding for C#. https://gist.github.com/BravoTango86/2a085185c3b9bd8383a1f956600e515f